# How to print in one line?

Tags: python-3.x

my question is that : how can print the password in one line or in one block ?
I want to know how to print output in a single line. 
my code is that :

```
import random
import string

char = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
lenght = random.randint(8, 16)

for i in range(lenght) :
    password = ''.join(random.choice(char))

    print('your password is === > ', password)
```

Comment: I did it, it prints only one letter instead of a few letters for the password

Answer (score 1):

I found a way and the letters were printed on one line

```
import random
import string
char = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
lenght = random.randint(8, 16)  
password = ''.join(random.choice(char) for x in range(lenght))
print('your password is === > ',password)
```